# Android dynamically buttons inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create a series of Buttons inside a LinearLayout. So I have the following code

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yearContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
```

**in my Activity**

```
LinearLayout yearContainer=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yearContainer);
for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
Button btn=new Button(this);
    btn.setText("Button "+i);
    btn.setId(150+i);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/3,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);

    yearContainer.addView(btn);

}
```

But the Buttons are arranging vertically. I need it as the following pattern.

[image]

I am new to android. Please advise

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what yo want with a single LinearLayout. You need to use either a TableLayout, or create several Horizontal LinearLayouts inside the Vertical LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there as mentioned before this can be done using the "Table Layout" or "Grid Layout". But I will also suggest you to use nested simple linear and horizontal layouts. This will make sure your layout will be supported even in phones with older version of Android OS. As Grid Layout requires API Level 14 or higher.

So the code below should get you the result you expected with simple layouts.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Sampleact_H"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="8" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="11" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="12" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="13" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="14" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="15" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="16" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```